# How to test an API locally in apiman?

Tags: apiman

**Desired Behaviour**

I want to test an apiman API locally in order to view the response of the [apiman-quickstarts/echo-service](https://github.com/apiman/apiman-quickstarts/tree/master/echo-service) (or if that is no longer applicable in the latest version of apiman, any echo response would be great).

**What I've Tried**

I installed `apiman` on `Ubuntu 17.10` using the following from the [the official apiman site](http://www.apiman.io/latest/download.html):

```
mkdir ~/apiman-1.3.1.Final
cd ~/apiman-1.3.1.Final
curl http://download.jboss.org/wildfly/10.1.0.Final/wildfly-10.1.0.Final.zip -o wildfly-10.1.0.Final.zip
curl http://downloads.jboss.org/apiman/1.3.1.Final/apiman-distro-wildfly10-1.3.1.Final-overlay.zip -o apiman-distro-wildfly10-1.3.1.Final-overlay.zip
unzip wildfly-10.1.0.Final.zip
unzip -o apiman-distro-wildfly10-1.3.1.Final-overlay.zip -d wildfly-10.1.0.Final
cd wildfly-10.1.0.Final
./bin/standalone.sh -c standalone-apiman.xml
```

Using the apiman GUI (`localhost:8080/apimanui/api-manager`), I created an `Organisation`, a `Public API` with no `API Security`, an `Endpoint` arbitrarily defined as `http://localhost:8080/apiman-echo`, and a `Client App`.  As the API is defined as `Public`, it is my understanding that no `Contract` needs to be defined in the `Client App`. 
 The `Managed Endpoint` of the API was provided in the GUI as:

```
https://localhost:8443/apiman-gateway/MyTestOrganisation/MyTestAPI/2.0
```

**Actual Behaviour**

These are the curl results:

```
# using the 'managed endpoint' provided in the gui - https
curl -k https://localhost:8443/apiman-gateway/MyTestOrganisation/MyTestAPI/2.0
<html><head><title>Error</title></head><body>404 - Not Found</body></html>

# using the 'managed endpoint' provided in the gui - http
curl -k http://localhost:8443/apiman-gateway/MyTestOrganisation/MyTestAPI/2.0
curl: (52) Empty reply from server

#using the endpoint i defined
curl -k http://localhost:8080/apiman-echo
<html><head><title>Error</title></head><body>404 - Not Found</body></html>
```

The crash course documentation ([apiman.io/latest/crash-course.html](http://www.apiman.io/latest/crash-course.html)) states that the following is the contents of the apiman folder, however a search for `quickstarts` in the `wildfly-10.1.0.Final` folder on my pc returns no results:

```
├── apiman
│   ├── data
│   │   ├── all-policyDefs.json
│   │   └── apiman-realm.json
│   ├── ddls
│   │   ├── apiman_mysql5.ddl
│   │   └── apiman_postgresql9.ddl
│   ├── quickstarts
│   │   ├── echo-service
│   │   ├── LICENSE
│   │   ├── pom.xml
│   │   └── README.md
│   └── sample-configs
│       ├── apiman-ds_mysql.xml
│       └── apiman-ds_postgresql.xml
```

I feel like I am missing a couple of steps somewhere that relate to "installing" the `echo-service` and making it available to test.

Searching for `echo` in [apiman.gitbooks.io/apiman-user-guide](https://apiman.gitbooks.io/apiman-user-guide/) and [apiman.gitbooks.io/apiman-production-guide](https://apiman.gitbooks.io/apiman-production-guide) produces no results, whilst [apiman.io/latest/developer-guide.html](http://www.apiman.io/latest/developer-guide.html) states:

> the mock back-end API is a simple "echo" API that responds to all
>   requests with a JSON payload describing the request it received

But I am not sure how to interpret and utilise that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have figured out a solution.

There is a section in a [blog post here](http://www.apiman.io/blog/introduction/overview/2015/01/09/impatient-new-user-redux.html) called "Getting and Building and Deploying the Example API" the content of which seems to be more relevant to earlier versions of apiman but generally holds true.

I document my process and result below in case it assists anyone else.

The following steps from the blog post resulted in a compilation error:

```
# make a directory on desktop to clone files into
mkdir ~/Desktop/my_container_for_echo_quickstart

# change into directory
cd my_container_for_echo_quickstart

# git clone
git clone https://github.com/apiman/apiman-quickstarts.git

# change into directory
cd apiman-quickstarts/echo-service/

# install maven so i can run `mvn package` 
sudo apt install maven

# run `mvn package`
mvn package
```

After logging lots of download information, the following error was displayed:

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 01:37 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-11-26T19:39:29+10:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 17M/242M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.2:compile (default-compile) on project apiman-quickstarts-echo-service: Compilation failure
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

And then I looked for java version and got the following:

```
java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_151"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-8u151-b12-0ubuntu0.17.10.2-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)
```

So I did this:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
mvn package
```

And got `BUILD SUCCESS`.  The blog post continues that:

> If you look closely, near the end of the output, you’ll see the
>   location of the .war file

It actually output the location of the `.jar` file:

```
Building jar: /home/me/Desktop/my_container_for_echo_quickstart/apiman-quickstarts/echo-service/target/apiman-quickstarts-echo-service-1.3.1.Final-javadoc.jar
```

But there was a `.war` file in the same directory:

```
apiman-quickstarts-echo-service-1.3.1.Final.war
```

So I copied that to `/home/me/apiman-1.3.1.Final/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/standalone/deployments`and saw the server output change in the other terminal:

```
20:10:54,463 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYDR0001: Content added at location /home/me/apiman-1.3.1.Final/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/standalone/data/content/c6/*****/content
20:10:54,482 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "apiman-quickstarts-echo-service-1.3.1.Final.war" (runtime-name: "apiman-quickstarts-echo-service-1.3.1.Final.war")
20:10:54,667 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 76) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: /apiman-echo
20:10:54,772 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "apiman-quickstarts-echo-service-1.3.1.Final.war" (runtime-name : "apiman-quickstarts-echo-service-1.3.1.Final.war")
```

This was the resulting curl results:

```
curl -k http://localhost:8080/apiman-echo
{
  "method" : "GET",
  "resource" : "/apiman-echo",
  "uri" : "/apiman-echo",
  "headers" : {
    "Accept" : "*/*",
    "User-Agent" : "curl/7.55.1",
    "Host" : "localhost:8080"
  },
  "bodyLength" : null,
  "bodySha1" : null
}
```

Whilst this is encouraging, I am concerned that because I set up the API in the apiman GUI first with the `/apiman-echo` endpoint, there will be a clash between it and the endpoint I created through the maven process, but we will see.